# python aiomuliprocess Producer-Consumer-model use queue can't get

Tags: python

I use `aiomultiprocess` pacakge to read some files and process data，when i use `multiprocess.Manger().queue()` can't `get()` queue data。
Who can help me? Thank you ver much.

OS Version: Windows10 22H2 X86_64
Python Version: Python 3.10

```
import random
from io import StringIO
from asyncio import Semaphore
import os
import asyncio

import aiofiles
import yaml
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from aiomultiprocess import Pool
from multiprocessing import Manager
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue


async def start():
    queue: Queue = Manager().Queue()

    producer_tasks = []
    async with Pool(processes=5) as pool:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(obs["ev"]):
            producer_tasks.extend([pool.apply(producer, args=(os.path.join(root, file), queue)) for file in files])

        consumer_task = asyncio.create_task(consumer(queue))
        await asyncio.gather(*producer_tasks)
        queue.put(None)
        await consumer_task


async def producer(path: str, queue: Queue) -> None:
    async with aiofiles.open(path, encoding="utf-8") as fp:
        content = await fp.read()
        df: DataFrame = pd.read_csv(StringIO(content))
        time: str = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
        queue.put({"time": time,
                   "df": df})
        queue.put(random.randint(1, 10))
        print(time)


async def consumer(queue) -> None:
    while True:
        data = queue.get()
        if data is None:
            break
        time = data["time"]
        df = data["df"]
        print(f"consumer: {time}")
        # xxx


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(r"./config/evaluation.yml", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        config = yaml.safe_load(f)
        obs = config["OBS"]
        asyncio.run(start())
```